# How to print object in key/value format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dnspython

The `print()` function outputs the result of a dns query below as a string, but I need to see the KEYS of this result. I tried using `pprint()`, `getmembers()`, `vars()`, and `dir()`, but they output a lot of irrelevant attributes and don't directly show the result like the `print()` function does:

```
import dns
req = dns.message.make_query('msn.com', dns.rdatatype.ANY)
res = dns.query.udp(req, '8.8.8.8', timeout=3)
print(res)

===========================================================
OUTPUT (Command Prompt)
===========================================================
id 12637
opcode QUERY
rcode NOERROR
flags QR RD RA
;QUESTION
msn.com. IN ANY
;ANSWER
msn.com. 685 IN A 23.101.196.141
msn.com. 21385 IN NS ns3.msft.net.
msn.com. 21385 IN NS ns4.msft.net.
msn.com. 21385 IN NS ns1.msft.net.
msn.com. 21385 IN NS ns2.msft.net.
msn.com. 21385 IN SOA ns1.msft.net. msnhst.microsoft.com. 2015080901 7200 900 2419200 900
msn.com. 685 IN MX 5 mx4.hotmail.com.
msn.com. 685 IN MX 5 mx1.hotmail.com.
msn.com. 685 IN MX 5 mx2.hotmail.com.
msn.com. 685 IN MX 5 mx3.hotmail.com.
msn.com. 685 IN TXT "v=spf1 include:Spf-a.hotmail.com include:Spf-b.hotmail.com include:Spf-c.hotmail.com include:Spf-d.hotmail.com include:_spf-ssg-a.microsoft.com include:Spf.protection.outlook.com ~all"
;AUTHORITY
;ADDITIONAL
```

How can I get an equivalent to the `print()` function result in object format (key/value pairs)? Something analogous to what a JSON object would look like, is this possible?

Comment: What is the `dns` library you're using there?  Is it [this one](http://www.dnspython.org/)?  If so, did you look in the documentation there?

Comment: `print(something)` will just call `__str__` method on that object. so it is like toString in Javascript. You need to read documentation for that library you are using how to iterate over keys/values and then just format it the way you like

Comment: So there's no convenience "`print()` as object" method or something like that? I can find the keys the hard way by doing some inspecting, but I'm wondering if there's an easier way like a simple "print()". (The docs for dnspython don't make it clear what the keys are either).

Comment: [The docs](http://www.dnspython.org/docs/1.12.0/) say that ```dns.query.udp``` returns a [```dns.message```](http://www.dnspython.org/docs/1.12.0/toc-dns.message-module.html) ```Message``` object, whcih doesn't appear to have any key:value attributes.

Comment: @Sunny: There can't be, because not everything that can be printed consists of keys and values.  What you want is some sort of structured representation of the object's data, but that may or may not be available depending on what kind of object it is.